# Why does isolated chlorophyl emits red light?

Tags: spectroscopy, photochemistry, fluorescence

If we observe isolated chlorophyl solution with UV light, chlorophyl is seen as red. Explanation suggests that when a specific atom of chlorophyl absorbs UV light, the atom gets excited and in a short time electrons still goes from excited state to ground state. But why it is not emits same wavelength light, and instead emits lower energy light - red ?

Comment: Many materials do that. Search for fluorescence.

Comment: Besides generally searching for “fluorescence”, see [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/141477/79678) and perhaps search in this stack exchange for other answers.

Comment: It isn't just isolated chlorophyll that does this. The effect can be seen with cheap handheld near-UV laser pointers and leaves.

Comment: Very basic and quick - I think is what you are asking for. As molecules are constituted of different part linked and vibrating, the upwards path can be closed once absorption occurred. Part of the energy is dissipated in rearranging the molecule and by vibrations. Then from a certain already lowered down level, emission occurs. As a starting point for more look indeed at the thread linked by Ed V. Wikipedia on the subject is also nice. Note that "isolated"guarantee emission, it is not functional to the fact that UV in / red out. A molecule which is not isolated can have its emission quenched..

Comment: ... because the surrounding can interact with it and remove the otherwise "to be emitted" energy.

Comment: Perhaps illustrating what @Alchimista and matt_black said, see how [quinine in tonic water](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/130758/79678) fluoresces when 405 nm light illuminates the solution. The main emission is a band around 460 nm, not just at 460 nm, and the emission can be quenched by adding ordinary table salt: the chloride ions effectively steal the energy from the excited quinine molecules before they can get rid of the energy by emitting light. The joke is that only 10% of all substances fluoresce and they are the wrong 10%!

Comment: @EdV indeed the "guarantee" I have used above is with the context given. OP: Isolated molecules can be not fluorescent, or doing it with a very small efficiency nevertheless.

Comment: There is nothing particularly unusual about using UV light to excite fluorescence of various colors: lots of minerals fluoresce when exposed to shortwave or long wave UV. Some people collect such minerals and the fluorescent colors are useful for identification purposes. And, of course, Stokes discovered fluorescence in fluorite (natural calcium fluoride), giving the phenomenon its name. Ruby fluoresces at 694.3 nm when excited with violet or yellow-green light.

Comment: Stunningly beautiful fluorescent mineral photos here: https://www.uvsystems.com/pages/tgms-fluorescent-displays.

Answer (score 3):

There are three types of re-emission when photons interact with matter:

- Emitting the *same* wavelength, e.g., simple reflection, [resonance fluorescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resonance_fluorescence) and [stimulated emission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stimulated_emission).
- Emitting *longer* wavelength due to losses in absorption of initial photon, e.g., [fluorescence and phosphorescence](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Spectroscopy/Electronic_Spectroscopy/Fluorescence_and_Phosphorescence) and [Compton scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_scattering).
- Emitting *shorter* wavelength than that incident. This occurs in [two photon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-photon_excitation_microscopy) or [multiphoton fluorescence](https://www.olympus-lifescience.com/en/microscope-resource/primer/techniques/fluorescence/multiphoton/multiphotonhome/). It requires the molecule stay in a metastable state long enough for a second photon to raise it to a higher yet state, requiring *intense* light. AFAIK, there is [some little literature on UV-incident multiphoton fluorescence](https://www.osapublishing.org/ao/abstract.cfm?uri=ao-37-13-2766), but I don't know if chlorophyll has been investigated.

Comment: I think it will be better to call "emit same wavelength" condition as resonance fluorescence rather than reflection. Atoms show this phenomenon in flames. If we excite Na atoms in flame by 589 nm, they will emit 589 nm.

Comment: Upvoted, but it is not clear to me what is puzzling the OP. Is it the matter of the “chlorophyl atom” not behaving like a hydrogen atom, i.e., it can absorb UV light, but fluoresces red? Or is the red fluorescence itself the issue? I think the former is what they are asking about, but unless they clarify or elaborate, not much more to say, I guess.